# orderBy - order objects by value

Tags: angularjs

I have this object:

```
{
  "EG": "Egypt",
  "EH": "Western Sahara",
  "ER": "Eritrea",
  "ES": "Spain",
  "ET": "Ethiopia",
  "FI": "Finland"
}
```

I have this ng-repeat:

```
<md-option ng-repeat="(code, country) in data.countries" value="{{code}}">{{country}}</md-option>
```

I would like to sort it by the country name, not by the code which is the current sort. Any ideas?

Comment: Transform this object into an array of objects with a key and a name, and use orderBy on that array.

Answer (score 2):

orderBy better with array of objects, key and value.

Try the **Filter** way:

javascript:

```
var app = angular.module('myapp',[]);

app.filter('orderObjectBy', function(){
 return function(input, attribute) {
    if (!angular.isObject(input)) return input;

    var array = [];
    for(var key in input) {
        array.push(input[key]);
    }

    array.sort(function(a, b){ 
        if(a < b) return -1;
        if(a > b) return 1;
        return 0;
    });
    return array;
 }
});
```

html:

```
<md-option ng-repeat="(code, country) in itemObjects | orderObjectBy:'country'" value="{{code}}">{{country}}</md-option>
```

[code example](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/zKgdJd)

Have fun.